# Regex URL breaking with certain characters

Tags: php, regex, url, urlencode

My regex works when doing things like `foo/bar` and `one with spaces/two with spaces/three with spaces/four with spaces` etc, but it directs to the 404 page when using `urlencode` in PHP.

The following test shows that encoded strings don't work in the URL:
http://regex101.com/r/jP0gW1

Anyone have any ideas? It also breaks when using the "+" character.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you were not handling the `%` in your regex. `\w` only matches alphanumerical characters.

Adding a % to your regex made it work:

```
^([\w\ ]+)(?:/([\w\ ]+))?(?:/([\w\% ]+))?(?:/([\w\ ]+))?(?:/([\w\ ]+))?(?:/([\w\ ]+))?/?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pP0hS7)

You can simplify your regex if you want to:

```
/^([\w\s%]+\/).*$/
```

Comment: Amit, he cannot use the simplified regex you suggest `/^([\w\s%]+\/).*$/` because he needs to capture tokens into various Groups to reuse in his replacement url.

Comment: @zx81, I said "if you want to"

Comment: This is not a fight or an attack. Sorry if it came across the wrong way.

Comment: @zx81, yes it isn't. ;)

Comment: Again, sorry if my comment offended you in any way. I like your work. :) Wishing you a relaxing weekend.

Comment: I used your suggestion `^([\w\s%]+)(?:/([\w\s%]+))?(?:/([\w\s%]+))?(?:/([\w\s%]+))?(?:/([\w\s%]+))?(?:/([\w\s%]+))?/?$`, but it still does not allow the + character.